# Why does this weird curly effect happens to my cloth?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to animate cloth handles, so I made a pinning group and applied cloth sim. I don't know why, but all of them are acting really weird even though the mesh is fine.

How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hmm hard to tell without your blend file, but my personal guess is 'Self-collisions', try to turn it off and see if it helped, it is possible that your 'Distance' value 0.015 is too big and it needs to be lower

Comment: Also, if you use a solidify modifier and/or a subsurf modifier (or any other) put them after the cloth simulation or disable them but as @MikoCG says, it's better you upload the file.

Comment: @MikoCG thank you so much  - this helped!

Comment: Hi. Please don't add "*Solved*" to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

MikoCG's suggestion to turn off *Self Collisions* solved the problem